# redshift revoke privlage from super_user

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

My redshift cluster super user password is known colleagues to whom it shuldn't be.
I had created a redshift cluster with a dbuser named :- ateam(super_user)

How can i revoke super_user privalge from ateam and grant only

`"Select" privilege  to ateam`

if it is not possible 
Apart from changing the db password is there any other way available to handle this situation

Like things i tried :-

> created another super_user :- bteam (with super user privalages) 
>    and tried to delete ateam (culdnt do tht)
>
> tried to revoke privilages from ateam (didn't work)

can experts here suggest me any other methords (apart from changing password)
thanks in advance

Hence asking the question here Any help would be really appreciated

Comment: Why don't you want to change the password? You should not have a superuser password encoded into any systems (since they wouldn't need elevated permissions), so it should only be DBAs using that login, and preferably each user has their own login rather than a shared login.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways,you can revoke privileges from the super user
Option 1.Alter user ateam nocreateuser; 
The above command revokes super user privileges from the super user.
Option 2.Same as you followed by creating another user bteam and make it a super user and delete the old user ateam but it will give error like objects are associated with it,so its difficult as there will be important object which cant deleted.

So option is 1 best in your situation and for option2 -to delete/drop the user ateam,you should remove super user privileges from the user.